# Identify this late 80s, possibly early 90s stand-up special with a comedian who sings "I don't care."

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I watched this stand-up comedy special at a friend's house sometime between 87-91.  It would have been on a premium channel (my guess is either HBO or Cinemax).

I don't remember if there were multiple acts, but there is one comedian who stands out in my mind.

He was Caucasian, slightly overweight (not by much though) and had, I think, short hair.

The part I remember about his act is that he had this song he sang called "I don't care."  He would just sing that over and over.  At one point he left the stage, went outside and started singing the song to people on the street.

He walked up to one guy and said something like "what are you doing?  scalping tickets?" and the guy looked like he was scalping tickets and had a pissed off look on his face.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are thinking of [**Kevin Meaney**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Meaney).

I even found him singing his song...